# SwiftUI: define view appearances with protocols

Tags: ios, swiftui, protocol-oriented

New to SwiftUI, I have seen that all UI components are now protocols or structs.

What I enjoy about protocols is the fact that I can combine them without needing inheritance, unlike object-oriented programming.

But then, I was wondering, how can I combine multiple view appearances, let's say I'd have a `BlueView` protocol that would define a view with a blue background, and a `RoundedCorner` protocol defining a view with rounded corners.

How can I do something like this:

`MyView: View, BlueView, RoundedCorner { ...`

In order not to have to set these lines of code in every view of my app?

```
Color.blue
.cornerRadius(8)
...
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not sure I understood what you try to do with those protocols? Would you show more code or prepare minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I think [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/encapsulating-swiftui-view-styles/) is the kind of thing you are looking for. You can't do it through composition since adding a protocol only *describes* behaviour. It doesn't implement behaviour.

Comment: Also, using composition doesn't mean you aren't using object oriented programming. Objects and structs in Swift can conform to protocols and substitutability is a key outcome of using protocols

Comment: Thank you for your comments and your help. It's more clear to me now.